# How To Tell How Many Elements Are In A Swift Stack

Tags: swift, stack

I am using Swift stacks for my calculator app that I am making. But I need to tell if there is only one element in my stack for my calculator app to function correctly. Does anybody know how to count the number of elements  in a Swift stack?

```
struct Stack {
    fileprivate var operators: [String] = []

    mutating func push(_element: String) {
        operators.append(_element)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> String? {
        return operators.popLast()
    }
    func peek() -> String? {
        return operators.last
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift doesn't have a native `Stack` implementation.  Are you perhaps using an array?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to know how many elements are in your `operators` property of *your* (not Swift's) `Stack` struct?

Comment: @vacawama I am using String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift doesn't have a built-in `Stack` type.

To reveal the size of *your* custom `Stack` `struct`, add a `size` property to your `Stack` that returns the number of items in the `operators` array:

```
struct Stack {
    fileprivate var operators: [String] = []

    mutating func push(_ element: String) {
        operators.append(element)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> String? {
        return operators.popLast()
    }

    func peek() -> String? {
        return operators.last
    }

    var size: Int { return operators.count }
}
```

**Example**

```
var stack = Stack()
stack.push("+")
print(stack.size)  // 1
_ = stack.pop()
print(stack.size)  // 0
```